# Convert HTML Input type DATE to MYSQL DATE

Tags: java, html, mysql, date

having difficulties converting back and forth date objects in HTML/Java/SQL:

I have a class that contains object type LocalDate.

With HTML the user enters a mm/dd/yyyy like 01/19/1993

But MYSQL only accepts date format yyyy-MM-dd

So I retrieve my date as part of httpservletrequest and try to convert back and forth when adding to database or loading from.

Any help is much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form action="PaymentControllerServlet" method="GET">
                <input type="hidden" name="command" value="ADD" />

                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Company Name:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="companyName" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Company Phone:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="companyNumber" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Bill Amount:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="paymentAmount" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Due Date:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="date" name="paymentDueDate" /></td>
                        </tr>
```

Java:

```
// 1)Retrieve date as a String, parse the String into actual Date object
        Date  date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("paymentDueDate"));

        // 2)Create a new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") - For mySQL format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        // 3)Convert my Date obj into String, and change to ("yyyy-MM-dd") format

        String myStringdate = sdf.format(date1);

        // 4)Convert String back to date obj

        Date finishedDate = (Date)sdf.parse(myStringdate);

        // 5)Convert to localDate
        LocalDate dueDate = finishedDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        // 6)Send to MYSQL database. 
        //Initial user html input = 01/19/1993, 
        //date entered in mysql database = 0184-12-31
```

Comment: Don't turn you date into a string when passing it to mysql; use a parameterised query that has a date typed parameter, and pass the java date you parsed from the http query string representation

Comment: Can you clarify your solution or post an example snippet I can tinker with?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4):

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Stop spinning your wheels manipulating strings. Use objects when interacting with your database.

Never use `Date` or `SimpleDateFormat`. Use only *java.time* classes.

As of [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), we can exchange some of the *java.time* types directly with the database.

First, parse your input string.

```
String input = "01/23/2019";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Pass via a `?` placeholder in a prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

All this has been covered many times on Stack Exchange already. Search to learn more.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).